# UISwitch is not visible in UITableview(iOS 8)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have created a UISwitch in UITableview but it is not visible in the exact row.Code which i referred and implemented in my project.Can anyone tell me how to correct it.

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

 UISwitch *switchBtn = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 50)];
 [switchBtn setOn:YES animated:YES];
 NSInteger row;
 switchBtn.tag=row;
 row =[indexPath row];
 [switchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchStateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 cell.accessoryView = switchBtn;
 [cell addSubview:switchBtn];

 UILabel *lblPhone =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 230, 30)];
 lblPhone.text = @"Change Default View as Month View";
 lblPhone.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:lblPhone];

}
-(IBAction)switchStateChanged:(id)sender
{
UISwitch *switchState = sender;

if(switchState.tag == 0)
{
     NSLog(@"ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"OFF");

    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:switchBtn];

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan i tried your code but still it is not showing.

Comment: It's not offscreen? What happens if you use same coordinates as the label? Also try to remove `cell.accessoryView = switchBtn;` and add it to the cell.contentView instead. Since the accessoryView it to the right, the frame seems a bit large

Comment: remove ` [cell addSubview:switchBtn];` and instead of `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 50)` use `initWithFrame:CGRectZERO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    UISwitch *switchBtn = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    [switchBtn setOn:YES animated:NO];
    switchBtn.tag=[indexPath row];
    [switchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchStateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.accessoryView = switchBtn;
    UILabel *lblPhone =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 230, 30)];
    lblPhone.text = @"Change Default View as Month View";
    lblPhone.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblPhone];

}
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
-(void)switchStateChanged:(id)sender
{
UISwitch *switchControl = sender;

if(switchControl.tag == 1)
{
    if (switchControl.isOn) {
        NSLog(@"on");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"off");
    }
}
}
```

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: if i used " cell.accessoryView = switchBtn;" it is not showing but if i used  [cell.contentView addSubview:switchBtn]; its showing ..

Answer (score 2):

A lot of your code makes little sense. For instance, `[switchBtn setOn:YES animated:YES];` is pointless when your switchButton isn't visible yet (that is, has not yet been inserted into a view hierarchy, no animation will occur.

Next, you declare a variable `row` with no value, and assign next the tag of the switch to it?? The result is probably undefined, and it is certainly not achieving anything meaningful for you. And what's the point of all that, if you simply need the row of `indexPath`?

Next, you assign your switchButton to the accessory view, and then you add it as a subview of the cell! One of the two is certainly unnecessary. Accessory view should be probably kept for a true 'accessory' feature (read the [UITableView doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) for that).

But the biggest issue to me, and your code is not clear about it, is how you deal with cell reuse. You have to be aware that cells are reused (`[tableView dequeueReusableCell...` methods). A cell created for a row, can be reused later by the table view instance in another row. And a common mistake is to create specific stuff for a cell, expecting it to stay where it first appears.

In that UITableView delegate method, you have to set *all* the properties of that particular cell for the row currently in consideration. That is, also making sure the switchButton is *not* present in cells of other rows.

It is hard to explain, but you should post the whole method implementation for us to have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

In Your code just replace 150 with 50

```
UISwitch *switchBtn = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 50, 50)];
```

and add this Line

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:switchBtn];
```

and Comment this line

```
//cell.accessoryView=switchBtn;
```

Answer (score 1):

The switch can also be added to accessory view,Just add the UITableView in storyboard without dragging the UITableViewCell in it(Dont add UITableViewCell).In this way in the above code the condition if(cell==nil) will be called.The below code works for me with accesoryView as UISwitch

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(indexPath.row==3){
        UISwitch *eventSwitch=[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        [eventSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleEventNotification:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.accessoryView=eventSwitch;

    }


}
cell.textLabel.text=[settingArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16];
return cell;
}
```